# PHP Sub-Classes for optional functionality

Tags: php, class, plugins, module, inner-classes

Our company has been accepted into a closed testing session for some software recently, where I have taken the API that is in development and began developing a wrapper class for us to use in our own systems.

The base class establishes a connection to the API, sends JSON requests and handles all of the core functionality. The system however operates on plugins/modules that add additional functionality when loaded.

Does PHP support sub-classes that would work for this scenario? Would it work best to pass an instance of the base class to the "sub-classes" as a parameter when they are initialized and use that for sending requests?

Pseudo Code:

```
<?php

class PluginClass
{
    private base = null;

    public function __construct($base_system)
    {
        if (isset($base_system))
        {
            $this->base = $base_system;
        }

        $this->base->sendRequest("someData");
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    public function __construct($host = 'localhost', $port = '8080', $user = 'admin', $pass = '')
    {
        if(!empty($host) && !empty($port) && !empty($user) && !empty($pass))
        {
            $this->login($host, $port, $user, $pass);
        }
    }

    public function sendRequest($data)
    {
        // Send JSON Request Data
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your sub-class didn't inherit `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly normal scenario.
I wouldn't call this `subclass` though to not to confuse this with child classes that extend parent class via `extend` mechanism.

What you describe I use almost every day.
Say, a class that is given an array to operate with.
Or another class that is given a database connection to operate upon.

For example,

```
$object_screwer = new ObjectScrewer( $some_object ); 
$object_screwer->screw_it();
```

...which it its turn calls `$this->object->some_method()` for example

Some also wrongfully call it the `strategy` pattern.
It isn't that by its definition, but it looks very similar.

---

Just to be clear, `strategy` pattern would be:

```
$P = new Payment( new PayPal('username','password') );
$P->pay(10.00);
```

In `strategy` pattern we give the initial object some parameters: not just properties, but defining the **strategy** of its behavior. In this case I created a payment object and gave it a PayPal plug-in object for the payment processing.

Good luck coding!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So rather than using inheritance/extending the "master" class, just passing the instance to the "plugin" class and calling the request() method from it will not cause any issues? In my head it works as shown via my pseudo code but I have to submit this to another developer for review, why I want to make sure its proper :)

Comment: No issue whatsoever. It's a normal classes use / pattern.  For example, `$object_screwer = new ObjectScrewer( $object ); $object_screwer->screw();` which then calls `$this->object->some_method()` for example